# Check value across tables when the field names are the same

Tags: mysql

I have several tables that I'm using in a query, and all of them have a column `deleted` that indicates if the record has been deleted or not (0 or 1).  What I've been doing is:

```
WHERE table1.deleted = 0 and table2.deleted = 0 and table3.deleted = 0)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to indicate the value for the same field name across tables, like:

```
WHERE *.deleted = 0
```

The above didn't work, obviously.  Can this be done?

Comment: How are you building up the query?  Hard-coded or dynamically in PHP or similar?  Also, is there a pattern to the table names you're looking at?  Depending on the answers to these, you might be able to do what you're trying to do--need more info.

Comment: It's a hard-coded query. And there is not a pattern to the table names.  Basically, I need to write the 'table.deleted = 0' on almost every join and every where clause for the outer query and any sub queries, so i was hoping there was a way to make it more implicit.

Comment: After 2 years and 5 months please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. You need to reference each column explicitly as in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bitwise <strike>or</strike> and

```
WHERE (table1.deleted & table2.deleted & table3.deleted) = 0
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-functions.html

Or even shorter:

```
WHERE NOT(table1.deleted & table2.deleted & table3.deleted)
```

**Disclaimer**
As David rightfully remarked, just because it can be done does not make it a good idea.
MySQL will not be able to use an index on this query, so this version will be slower than your original version.

Comment: (slight) syntactic shortening at the expense of losing index'

Comment: @David, not saying that it is a good idea, but it **can** be done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion here's a potential solution.  Depending on the number of queries and subqueries you'll be writing that need `tableX.deleted = 0` in it for every referenced table, it might be worth the minimal time to setup views on those tables.  Something like this for each table:

```
CREATE VIEW table1deleted AS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE deleted = 0;
```

Then in your queries you select from `table1deleted` instead of `table1`, because all the items in the `table1deleted` views are already filtered by `deleted = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't a way to do this directly in SQL, consider storing your SQL expressions in an external file, and using a tool to generate them that will allow you to store repeated expressions at macros. Or you could write functions to generate the SQL in whatever language you are coding in.

Tricks like the one Johan suggested may reduce performance, and your real goal here is to make the SQL expressions easier to deal with. So **the solution is to stop hard coding them** and handle them in a more sophisticated way.